# How can I set up OpenCV on Clion for mac?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clion

I cannot for the life of me add OpenCV to clion for mac and it driving me crazy. I looked at every resource available online and there is almost no documentation for setting it up on clion.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite frustrating, I know. Not to many resources, but here how I did it:

**1. Install homebrew (Library Manager):** https://brew.sh/

**2. Install OpenCV using homebrew:** https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/opencv#default

**3. Open a new Project in CLion**

**4. Edit the CMakeList.txt of the project to the following:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#find_library(OpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(ProjectName main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ProjectName ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

**5. Test the library by displaying an image**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
  cv::Mat srcImage = cv::imread("/Users/michelsmacbookpro/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/image.jpg"); // Use full path!
  cv::imshow("[img]", srcImage);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to help anyone trying to do this on an M1 mac. I was having lots of trouble. Add `set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64)` before `project()` in your CMakeLists.txt!